# google search console error indexing a not-ever-created page

Tags: http-status-code-404, google-crawlers, google-search-console

google search console indexes a few URLs that I haven't created. These routes never existed and the following checkups have been done:

1. robot.txt works well;
2. No hackers messed with the website;
3. browsing results in the website's 404 error.
   I'm using the console's removal tool but I'm searching for a **better solution that needs less manual handling of things**.
   Thanks for the answears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By index I presume they are reported under coverage as excluded?

If they 404 and are excluded, you don't need to use the removal tool. They are effectively removed already.

Google is just reporting that for some reason they found the URL, and then are telling you they know it should not be indexed.

They most likely found the URL due to a link to it. Maybe a typo for a link, or even a link from years ago. If it looks like a mistake you could try and fix the link and/or set up a 301 redirect from the bad URL to the right one.

Otherwise, it is fine to ignore reported 404s.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  That was exactly as you said! Those bad URLs caused it. I appreciate it.